# Compilation error on file lib/phoenix_ecto/html.ex

Tags: web, frameworks, window, elixir, phoenix-framework

While compiling a project which use elixir with phoenix web framework, the following compilation error occurs:

```
==> phoenix_ecto 
Compiled lib/phoenix_ecto.ex 
Compiled lib/phoenix_ecto/plug.ex 
Compiled lib/phoenix_ecto/ison.ex 
==> Compilation error on file lib/phoenix_ecto/html.ex == 
** (CompileError) ib/phoenix_ecto/html.ex:7: unknown key :impl for struct Phoenix.HTML.Form 
(elixir) src/e ixir_map.erl:175: :elixir_map.--assert_struct_keys/5-1c$"011-0--/5 
(elixir) src/e ixir_map.erl:48: :elixir_map.translate_struct/4 
(elixir) src/e ixir_clauses.erl:36: :elixir_clauses.clause/7 
(elixir) src/e ixir_def.erl:178: :elixir_def.translate_clause/7 
(elixir) src/e ixir_def.erl:167: :elixir_def.translate_definition/8 
[31m[1mcould not compile dependency phoenix_ecto, mix compile failed. You can recompile this dependency with 'mix deps.compile phoenix_ecto' or update it with 'mix deps.update phoenix_ecto'
```

How can I get my project to compile correctly?

Comment: It would probably be better to paste this snippet as text instead of an image.

Comment: I will update my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forget to install and compile my application's source code and dependencies with `mix do deps.get, compile`. I just only install and compile under phoenix directory. Then error emitted like above. After installed and compile under my application. It do well with no error.

Comment: could you replace the image in your question with the error text? Helps Google with indexing

Answer (score 6):

You need to update both phoenix_ecto and phoenix_html. Try this:

```
mix deps.clean phoenix_ecto phoenix_html
mix deps.update phoenix_ecto phoenix_html
```

And you should hopefully be good to go!

Comment: Still above error even I tried clean and update deps.

Answer (score 0):

As clearly mentioned in the error message, try:

```
mix deps.compile phoenix_ecto
```